# Eclipse Android isn't generated R.java

Tags: android, r.java-file

It's my first time developing for android. I'm trying to develop in eclipse environment, but I have a problem. The class R.java isn't generated. I've already tried everything like function clean or refresh->clean, and reinstall eclipse. Maybe the problem can be in my layout:

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in any of your xml files?

Comment: There are many reasons why [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)... like importing `android.R` and a typo in your XML.

Comment: Also check your imports, if it contacts android.R.java then remove it from the imports.

Comment: are your class files in src --> your package name?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean it isn't being regenerated?  This problem comes up a lot in Eclipse.  Just delete the existing R.java and it will regenerate correctly.

Or do you mean you have no R.java at all?

Comment: No. My Eclipse isn't generated R.java. Instead of it's generated this class:
/** Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY */
package com.example.hello;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public final static boolean DEBUG = true;
}

Comment: The BuildConfig class should be generated additionally to the R class. You can check the DEBUG constant from code to see if it's compiled with or without debugging.

Comment: How did you create this project?  The New Android Application wizard always creates an R file by default.

Comment: I created my project normally, new->android project.
Nobody knows how to solve my problem.. =/ I want to develop in Eclipse, but just my Netbeans is working...